# How to use random proportional editing?

Tags: edit-mode

https://ibb.co/fvjwCjf I'd like to have the orange line randomly peaking downwards. In this case, it only made the faces above it random. I'd also appreciate some further tips on (random) edge editing.

Comment: I think that is because all the highlighted vertices (the orange ring) are affected by your movements and any other vertices int he Mesh are affected if they are in the Proportional editing area of influence.

Comment: I can explain more detailedly what I'd like to achieve: 1. He selects the ring in edit mode: https://ibb.co/1XpqYL7   2. Then he presses "G" and drags his mouse down. Automatically, the vertices are dragged down with different "heights": https://ibb.co/Wv79RRs. I could select the vertices individually, I found, but that would be overly time consuming, I think, and so on. If you like to see what he did on your own, here's the video with timestamp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Gb1VK98Wc&t=1995s.

Answer (score 2):

The Proportional editing only affects vertices in the circle of influence (Scroll wheel to resize)

[image]
[image]

The default cube is subdivided and I selected a single vertex. Then with the Proportional editing set to random Grabbed and translated on the X axis. Note which vertices are affected.

[image]

Then I selected more vertices and repeated the process. Note which vertices are affected now.

I also tried it on a Mesh Circle and the same results occured. I did have to make the circle of influence very very big to affect all the unselected vertices in the circle.

In the video you cannot see the circle of influence, I am guessing it is so big it is off the edge of his viewport.

Comment: I've made the circle very very large and it still keeps a straight edge. The cricle, as I experienced, is rather how fine the random scattering is, the smaller the circle, the finer the scattering. I've precisely tried this after your post.

Comment: Open a new Blend file and delete the default cube and add a Mesh Circle and enter Edit mode. Select a single vertex and enable Proportional editing and Random fall off. Press G and Z and slowly move the mouse down. The single vertex should move down along with the random movement of couple next to it. Now increase the influence by scrolling the mouse wheel and more and more vertices should start to randomly move down. The View you use will greatly affect the way the influence circle effects vertices.

Answer (score 2):

The way proportional editing works in Blender is:

1. You make a selection of elements. Everything in the selection is considered to be under 100% influence of any transform you make subsequently
2. You set the radius and function-curve of *falloff* from those 100%-influenced points, where the distance is either measured in a circle around the current transform center, projected from the current point of view, or by accumulated connected edge-length through the mesh.

Because you have selected all the vertices, they are all 100% influenced by your <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

Select 1 vertex: it will move by the whole of the requested transform, and all other vertices within the Prop. Edit radius will be in the area of falloff, and, in your case, move by a random extent, according to a randomly varying falloff 'curve'.

Personally I much prefer the system adopted by 3DS and others, where you can make and edit soft *selections*, and then do whatever you want to them, proportionately to the selection weights.